# google geospatial inaccuracy

Tags: google-visualization, augmented-reality, geospatial, arcore, google-street-view

I've been working with Google Geospatial for a while now, I have two problems,

1- It doesn't work as accurately as it is shown in the videos, it sometimes shows inaccuracy up to 10 meters.

2- We don't know exactly what  Where does vps work, is there a list of cities where vps works completely and correctly?